# How can I update View after re-install of app using Cloudkit and Core Data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have a UIKit and SwiftUI app (mixed) and I have implemented Core Data and Cloudkit. My app is able to store and retrieve data.

If I delete the app and then reinstall it, the data is downloaded from iCloud.

The issue is in order to see this new data, I have stop the app and restart. The local data store does not reflect the changes until I close the app and restart it.

Is there a way to have the View updated when new records arrive from Cloudkit ?

Thanks

Comment: I don’t think you can force an update but make sure your setup is correct such as enabling background notifications. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/syncing_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit

Comment: @omid In other words, what I am seeing is normal behaviour ? I might be better off with Firebase then..

Comment: @Justin, I did not get what you mean? can you explain more plz?

Comment: @Omid If a user installs my app, uses it then changes iPhones. When that user installs my app on their new phone, they will have to start the app and then stop it and then restart it to see their content. Given how Cloudkit works, is there anyway around this or is this expected behaviour for Cloudkit ?

Comment: @Justin, you need to show your codes and be more exact what is your goal, but for your general Answer, if you delete your app, everything connected to that would be deleted unless you store it in cloud, how you would be able read those stored data from cloud it depends on your code or your method.